# How does Magento prevent two products with same sku being saved?

Tags: validation

What code is being used to prevent two products with same sku from being saved, is it at the attribute level (setting it as unique) or is there some other code being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is at the attribute level which B00MER says.

The attribute has "Unique Value" = true.

The attribute backend will extend
`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract` which has a `validate` function which includes a bit of logic like:

```
    if ($this->getAttribute()->getIsUnique()) {
        if (!$this->getAttribute()->getEntity()->checkAttributeUniqueValue($this->getAttribute(), $object)) {
            $label = $this->getAttribute()->getFrontend()->getLabel();
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav',
                Mage::helper('eav')->__('The value of attribute "%s" must be unique', $label)
            );
        }
    }
```

The `checkAttributeUniqueValue` will do a bit of logic which will query the database to see if there is an entity with the attribute already specified like defined. (The below snippet is edited for brevity, removed some of the EAV logic and just left it looking at static attributes)

```
public function checkAttributeUniqueValue(Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract $attribute, $object)
{
    $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();
    $select = $adapter->select();

    $value = $object->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
    $bind = array(
        'entity_type_id' => $this->getTypeId(),
        'attribute_code' => trim($value)
    );

    $select
        ->from($this->getEntityTable(), $this->getEntityIdField())
        ->where('entity_type_id = :entity_type_id')
        ->where($attribute->getAttributeCode() . ' = :attribute_code');

    $data = $adapter->fetchCol($select, $bind);

    if ($object->getId()) {
        if (isset($data[0])) {
            return $data[0] == $object->getId();
        }
        return true;
    }

    return !count($data);
```

This querying of the database means that the unique property of the attribute is not enforced at the database layer. This means that if you have race conditions with reading or writing, it is *very* possible to get products with duplicate SKUs in magento.

Comment: where does this validate function get called, what triggers it

Comment: Pretty sure the adminhtml catalog product controller will call it on the validate action.

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding it is only at the attribute level.

[image: Screenshot of attribute]

Comment: Can confirm, it's even possible to change it, but no, that's not a good idea